# cracked passenger side mirror

Tags: mercury, mirrors

Has anyone ever changed the passenger side mirror glass on a 2009 Mercury Mariner/Ford Escape? I cracked mine a few months ago and w/ the winter cold this crack is only getting bigger. I ordered a new one from Autozone and I'm almost sure this process is easy but just wanted to hear from others.

Comment: What year is your vehicle?

Comment: 2009. a coworker of mine let me know it should just pop out

Comment: I agree with your coworker. [Here's what it should look like](https://www.rockauto.com/info/909/88212%20Back_W__ra_p.jpg).